# Ment.io: can it show description for user typed when mouse over the user name?

Tags: angularjs, contenteditable

I wonder whether it is possible to show description for user filled by ment io when I mouse hover over the user name.

http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io

Step 1. @iqbal then ment.io will show suggestions: choose [~Iqbal]

Step 2. hover mouse over [~Iqbal] , is it possible to show some tooltip over it with description inside the tooltip.

Thanks